# Fix leak in Gardena T1030d water timer

Tags: watering, hoses, repair

My -so far- trusted gardena T1030d water timer has sprung a leak and I am at a bit of a loss.
I contacted the official service and they gave me advice but I am unable to reach the spot they indicated and I am also afraid to be a bit rough on the thing.
Anyway, I want to unscrew #7 to reach #8 but I cannot unscrew it.[image]

I am at this stage and #7, the grey thing is just revolving and not getting unscrewed with any kind of combination I tried (pulling & turning, pushing and turning etc..). I suspect I would may have to remove the little bolts (#9) but I am not sure if it is neccessary, or even how to do it. Any advice? THanks a lot [image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure from the diagram, but it doesn't look like #7 unscrews... it looks like it just pulls out; I think that you need to remove the pins (#9), and then pull #7 and #10 apart.

Again, you can't tell from the diagram whether the pins unscrew or not... they might be pushed in.

Comment: Thanks a lot or the answer. I ll try this. As soon as I manage to remove the pins..